# How do I get coverage to recognize an exit error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, coverage.py

My goal is to reach 100% coverage on unit tests I'm writing (`Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`)

The code I'm testing has exit messages of the form:

```
class _ExitStatus(enum.Enum):
    """The exit statuses."""
    success = _ExitStatusPair(
        0, "success")
```

I have the unit test code correctly triggers the `_exit_abnormally` function:

```
def _exit_abnormally(name, message):
    """Exit the program with the provided status and message."""
    try:
        print(message, file=sys.stderr)
    finally:
        sys.exit(getattr(_ExitStatus, name).value.status)
```

which correctly returns the error code 18. But `coverage` does not note that `_exit_abnormally` was called

```
class TestThis(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_(self):
    with self.subTest(args=args):
        args = (
        'python',
        _EXECUTABLE,
        'foo',
        'bar'
        )
        subprocess.run([x for x in args], check = True)
        try:
             print(subprocess.check_output([x for x in args]))
        except: subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
             print(" stdout output:\n", e.output)
             print(" stdout output:\n", e.returncode                
             self.assertEqual(e.returncode,18)
```

The assertion returns True, but when running the coverage report, the `_exit_abnormally` function still flags as a missing line.

How do I get `coverage` to reconize that `_exit_abnormally` was called?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible case? Perhaps as an issue at https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy?